# How to automatically reload the updated data after clicking the delete button

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my delete button.  It works fine on deleting the preferred delete data.  But, after I deleted the data, the data stay in the table and need to refresh.  Only then the undeleted data will be displayed.

*delete button*

```
<td>
    <a href = "javascript:delete_type( <?php echo $row[ 'id_vehicleType' ]; ?>)">
        <i class       = "fa fa-trash"
           aria-hidden = "true">
        </i>
    </a>
</td>
```

*javascript*

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function delete_type( id_vehicleType )
    {
        if ( confirm( 'Confirm Delete?' ) )
        {
            window.location.href = 'adminVehicleType.php?typeid = ' + id_vehicleType;
        }
    }
</script>
```

*php*

```
    // delete record
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'typeid' ] ) )
    {
        $del_vectype = "DELETE FROM vehicleType
                        WHERE id_vehicleType = " .
                            $_GET[ 'typeid' ];

        mysqli_query( $link,
                      $del_vectype );
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to redirect after delete header(Location:your_list_page.php);

Comment: does the page reload? does the data get deleted from the db? this is dangerously insecure, please dont use it in production

Comment: @JYoThI he does it the the javascript

Comment: he just navigating another url with id and there he deleting see him php code @nogad

Comment: yes. the data got deleted..but i need to refresh it again.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: Your delete code is in the same listing page?

Comment: yup..everthing is in the same page..

Comment: Then your delete query should be placed above the select query

Comment: You can use ajax : link for deletion -> ajax calls php -> php deletes and send response -> response OK -> jquery to remove parent div

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicleType ORDER BY vehicle_Type";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);


// delete record
if (isset($_GET['typeid'])) {
    $del_vectype = "DELETE FROM vehicleType WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid'];
    mysqli_query($link, $del_vectype);
}

Comment: already did.....

Comment: @yuki, check my answer below

Comment: @yuki : no you did not make use of jquery / ajax but plain js redirection

Comment: @nogad can you explain to me why this is insecure. i have no idea why? i have lacks experience with php

Comment: Let's say a brand new type of car just came in, named 1'); drop table cars --; poor little bobby ^^ http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: im sorry..still didnt understand  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your code for the delete query is placed above the code for the select query. If not, then please move your delete query above select query.

Delete query should come before select query

```
// delete record 
if (isset($_GET['typeid'])) {     
  $del_vectype = "DELETE FROM vehicleType WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid']; 
  mysqli_query($link, $del_vectype); 
}

//select data
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicleType ORDER BY vehicle_Type"; 
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Comment: it worked! thanks..sorry. i didnt realize that u said above. thankssssss.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class in element td like this:

```
<td><a class="btn-delete" data-id="<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType']; ?>" 
href="javascript:delete_type(<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType']; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

With Jquery you use to remove after confirm:

```
if (confirm('Confirm Delete?')){
    window.location.href = 'adminVehicleType.php?typeid=' + id_vehicleType;
  //remove element after update
   $('.btn-delete[data-id='+id_vehicleType +']').parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. This is one approach. Not sure why it's been down voted. May be approach is correct but delete statement not pointing the row